# android can't compress recycled bitmap error

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am trying to upload images to server so, I get images from gallery and put them in array of bitmaps and save the first image in separate bitmap called icons. In AsyncTask class, I scale the images with the sizes greater than 2048*1152 using the function `getResizedBitmap` then I take the icon and try to compress it to small size But here I got the following error And this error only appears when I get images with dimensions greater than 2048*1152:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:400)
                                                                                     at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1310)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.animal_project.Main_Menu_frgments.ads_fragment.get_icon(ads_fragment.java:219)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.animal_project.Main_Menu_frgments.ads_fragment.access$700(ads_fragment.java:52)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.animal_project.Main_Menu_frgments.ads_fragment$Encode_image.onPostExecute(ads_fragment.java:210)
                                                                                     at com.example.user.animal_project.Main_Menu_frgments.ads_fragment$Encode_image.onPostExecute(ads_fragment.java:180)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

here is where I get Images from Gallery:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    System.out.println("r111 is:"+data.toString());
    if(data!=null)
    {

        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();


            icons=new Bitmap[1];
            bitmaps_group=new Bitmap[clipData.getItemCount()];
            files=new File[clipData.getItemCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                Uri uri = item.getUri();

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

                    bitmaps_group[i]=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);

                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        icons[0]=bitmaps_group[0];
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(i==4)
                    i=clipData.getItemCount()+1;
            }
            new Encode_image().execute();
        }
       }
```

here is tha AsyncTask Class to check the size of images and calling the function that makes the icon :

```
private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            images_array=new String[bitmaps_group.length];
            for(int i=0;i<bitmaps_group.length;i++) {

                if(bitmaps_group[i].getHeight()>1160 ||bitmaps_group[i].getWidth()>2060)
                    try {
                        bitmaps_group[i]=getResizedBitmap(bitmaps_group[i],2048,1152);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                bitmaps_group[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();

                encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
                images_array[i]=encoded_string;

                System.out.println("Respon1:" + bitmaps_group.length);
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            icon_string=get_icon();
        }
    }

private String get_icon() {
        String encoding = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        icons[0].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, stream);
        byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();

        encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
        encoding=encoded_string;
        return encoding;
    }
```

Here is the function I used to change the size of images :

```
 public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) throws IOException {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        int rotation=0;

        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        Matrix matrix=new Matrix();

        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);


        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,true);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling `recycle()` on `Bitmap` objects anywhere?

Comment: Sorry i didn't put the function before , I edited the question and added the function

Comment: Why are you returming a recycyled bitmap?